# How to make take profit and stop loss work

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=4
strategy("sma")

dropdown menu to change the values of the EMA periods, stop loss, and take profit levels:
emaShortPeriod = input(100, minval=1)
emaLongPeriod = input(150, minval=1)
stopLoss = input(100, minval=0)
takeProfit = input(5, minval=0)

//use the input values to define the EMA series:
emaShort = sma(close, emaShortPeriod)
emaLong = sma(close, emaLongPeriod)

//use the input values to define the long and short entry signals:
longEntry = crossover(emaShort, emaLong)
shortEntry = crossover(emaLong, emaShort)

//plot the long and short entry signals on the chart:
plotchar(longEntry, "Long Entry", "▲", location.top, color = #00FF00, transp = 0)
plotchar(shortEntry, "Short Entry", "▼", location.top, color = #FF0000, transp = 0)

//function to generate market orders when the entry signals are triggered:
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=longEntry, stop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopLoss), limit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfit))
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=shortEntry, stop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopLoss), limit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takeProfit))
```

Stop loss and take profit have no effect

I am expecting the take profit and stop loss to have an effect on the chart and strategy tester.

Answer (score 0):

The `stop` and `limit` arguments of the `strategy.entry()` function are for limit type entries.

You should use the `strategy.exit()` function for your exits.

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=longEntry)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=shortEntry)

strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopLoss), limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfit))
strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Shoer", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopLoss), limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takeProfit))
```

Comment: //function to generate market orders when the entry signals are triggered:
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=longEntry)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=shortEntry)

strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopLoss), limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfit))
strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopLoss), limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takeProfit))